# Rails app, capistrano, nginx & puma 502 bad gateway

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, capistrano, puma

I'm getting a 502 when hitting my rails app.

`2018/12/22 20:12:37 [error] 22034#22034: *81 connect() to unix:/home/user/project/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: xx.xx.xx.xx, server: localhost, request: "GET /api/v1/login HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/user/project/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock:/500.html", host: "xx.xx.xx.xx"`

Is there a better way to troubleshoot this by finding a more descriptive error?

Comment: Puma needs a restart after deploy. Try to restart puma server. Also, check puma log

Comment: check and share the logs in the location "/var/log/nginx/error.log"

Comment: @vinodpasupathy thats what this

Comment: @styler1972 your app server(puma) is not running.